# Как реализовать управление с помощью поворота экрана (blueprints)?

Tags: разработка-игр, unreal-engine-4

Только начал осваивать движок UE4. Персонаж игры - шарик. Надо сделать так, чтобы я двигал шариком с помощью поворота экрана телефона (гироскопа, если это так называется). Подскажите пожалуйста как такое реализовать? Желательно с помощью блюпринтов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно искать информацию о применении гироскопа в смартфоне, с помощью него реализуются подобные манипуляции, вот небольшой [пример](https://projectboard.engineering.com/project/how-to-use-android-gyroscope-inputs-in-unreal-engine-4) и [[видео][2](https://youtu.be/Kog3GYzlCa4)](https://youtu.be/Kog3GYzlCa4).

Comment: Проблема как раз в том, что не могу найти пример использования

Comment: В Unreal Engine 4 есть плагины с библиотека функций для android и ios, попробуйте среди них поискать функционал связанный с гироскопом. Скорее всего на Blueprints нету того что вы ищите но в C++ наверняка есть.

Comment: я пробовал один из стандартных проектов компилировать (если Вы о них). В качестве управления на андроид устройствах там стандартно стики идут экранные. Гироскопа нет

Comment: Нет, я говорю о плагинах которые идут вместе с движком. Они находятся в Edit->Plugins

Comment: Спасибо, поищу.

Answer (score 0):

Если погулять по ссылкам, найдётся множество способов реализации. Я использовал Tilt и Add Torque
https://forums.unrealengine.com/development-discussion/blueprint-visual-scripting/36127-accelerometer-or-gyroscope-control-of-player